# In Julia, are there any methods to accelerate the 'dot product' and 'hcat' operations?

Tags: performance, math, matrix, statistics, julia

I've attempted a straightforward matrix calculation in Julia, but it's quite large.It's running very slowly. Are there any methods to speed it up?

```
a = ones(1000000,200)
b = ones(1000000,1).*2

@time begin
hcat((a.*(b.^2)), (a.*b),a)
end
```

Additionally, I have a follow-up question. The cumulative computation takes much longer than when processing each part individually. In other words, the previously mentioned code is slower than the one I'm about to show. Why might that be?

```
@time begin
temp1 = (b.^2)
end

@time begin
temp2 = a.*temp1
end

@time begin
temp3 = (a.*b)
end

@time begin
result = hcat(temp2,temp3,a)
end
```

I do not want use parallel calculation like @threads.

Answer (score 2):

1. You are bench-marking incorrectly. `@time` is measuring compilation time. Use instead @btime from `BenchmarkingTools`. See for discussion [Difference between the built-in @time macros and the ones from the benchmark module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73986570/difference-between-the-built-in-time-macros-and-the-ones-from-the-benchmark-mod)
2. The main problem with your code are allocations. You could largely avoid them by using `BlockArrays` instead.
3. `@simd` can speed up the single-threaded code. However this helps or not - SIMDed code needs to have no branching and several operations such as broadcasting use SIMD. See for discussion https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MUGQnq7mkSs
4. Multiplication is faster than `^2`

Below some illustrative examples.

Benchmarking the original code:

```
julia> @btime begin
       hcat(($a.*($b.^2)), ($a.*$b),$a)
       end
  3.114 s (32 allocations: 7.45 GiB)
1000000×600 Matrix{Float64}:
 4.0  4.0  4.0  4.0  4.0  …  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
 ...
```

Code `using BlockMatrices` to avoid additional allocations is 3x as fast:

```
julia> @btime begin
          mortar(( $a.* ($b .* $b), ($a .* $b), $a))
       end
  1.186 s (13 allocations: 2.98 GiB)
1×3-blocked 1000000×600 BlockMatrix{Float64}:
 4.0  4.0  4.0  4.0  4.0  …  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
 ...
```

You could a consider writing a SIMD code (this also yields a regular Matrix but the code is more complex) :

```
function calc(a,b)
  res = Matrix{Float64}(undef, size(a,1), size(a,2)*3)
  J = size(a,2)
  @view(res[:, 2J+1:3J]) .= a
  for j in 1:J 
      @inbounds @simd for i in 1:size(a,1)
         res[i, J+j] = a[i,j]*b[i,1]
      end
  end
  for j in 1:J 
      @inbounds @simd for i in 1:size(a,1)
         res[i, j] = res[i, J+j]*b[i,1]
      end
  end       
  res
end
```

Simd performs really well and yields a regular Matrix:

```
julia> @btime calc($a,$b)
  1.089 s (2 allocations: 4.47 GiB)
1000000×600 Matrix{Float64}:
 4.0  4.0  4.0  4.0  4.0  …  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

More than 50% of the time is already spent in allocating a huge 4.47 GiB array, but we can still squeeze out some performance gain for the remaining 50% using LoopVectorization.jl.

```
using LoopVectorization

function hcat3(a, b)
    I, J = size(a)
    res = Matrix{Float64}(undef, I, 3J)
    @turbo res[:,    1: J] .= a .* (b .* b)
    @turbo res[:,  J+1:2J] .= a .* b
    @turbo res[:, 2J+1:3J] .= a
end
@btime hcat3($a, $b) # 1.157 s (2 allocations: 4.47 GiB)
@btime calc($a, $b)  # 1.323 s (2 allocations: 4.47 GiB)
@btime hcat(($a.*($b.^2)), ($a.*$b),$a) # 1.883 s (6 allocations: 7.45 GiB)
```